# Interactions with kinect version 2

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, kinect

I'm just starting developing with Kinect version 2 (SDK 2.0) and am trying out a windows store app with kinect support. I've followed one of microsoft's videos in order to set up basic interactions with a grid app. You add the following lines of code in the App.xaml.cs file:

```
KinectRegion region = new KinectRegion();
KinectUserViewer viewer = new KinectUserViewer() {
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
    Width = 121,
    Height = 100
};
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Children.Add(region):
grid.Children.Add(viewer);
region.Content = rootFrame;
Window.Current.Content = grid;
```

I'm getting no error reports or exceptions and the user viewer comes up fine. There are no interactions however. Whatever I do I cannot get the hand icon to appear on screen like in the demo.

Any help or suggestions as to what's going wrong would be much appreciated.

P.S. I'm new to windows development, I have an Apple background.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this a month ago, but have you turned on the Microphone and Webcam features in your Package.appxmanifest file? It's under the Capabilities tab.

Comment: Yes I have. That's step one.